# What's the correct Traversal for ONE of the Templated Elements to Appear with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, traversal

Using handlebars as the view engine for node.js, the following html is dynamically generated, repeatedly http://jsfiddle.net/4Q5PE/:

```
<div class="btnsContainer">
  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn1"><input type="checkbox" class="theBtn1">btn1</label>
    <label class="btn btn2"><input type="checkbox" class="theBtn2">btn2</label>
    <label class="btn btn3"><input type="checkbox" class="theBtn3">btn3</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="Div1" style="display:none;">div1</div>

<div class="Div2" style="display:none;">div2</div>

<div class="Div3" style="display:none;">div3</div>
```

And I have this jQuery to toggle elements, but the matching repeated elements appear ALL together!

```
$(document).on("change",".theBtn1",function () {
    var $that = $(".Div1");
    $that.slideToggle();
    $(".btn2").removeClass("active");
    $(".btn3").removeClass("active");
    $(".Div1").not($that).slideUp();
    $(".Div2").not($that).slideUp();
    $(".Div3").not($that).slideUp();
});
...
```

I have tried various versions of jQuery traversing (.parent, .children, .siblings, .next, .previous), but what's a workable combination for getting only ONE element to appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make much more easier, if you can wrap the target div's in another container like

```
<div class="btnsContainer">
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn1"><input type="checkbox" class="theBtn1"/>btn1</label>
        <label class="btn btn2"><input type="checkbox" class="theBtn2"/>btn2</label>
        <label class="btn btn3"><input type="checkbox" class="theBtn3"/>btn3</label>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="Div1" style="display:none;">div1</div>
    <div class="Div2" style="display:none;">div2</div>
    <div class="Div3" style="display:none;">div3</div>
</div>
```

then

```
$(document).on("change", ".theBtn1", function () {
    var $nxt = $(this).closest('.btnsContainer').next();
    $nxt.children().not('.Div1').stop().slideUp().removeClass("active");;
    $nxt.children('.Div1').stop().slideToggle().toggleClass("active");;
});
```

Comment: @StackThis there are quite a few problems in this... what are you trying to do

Comment: Would like to do 3 things.. First, Div A/B/C should be hidden and should slidetoggle when theBtn1/2/3 changes, and should slideUp the other 2 of Div A/B/C on this change. Second, Div4-1 should slidetoggle when Div3-1 is clicked, and should slideUp when Div3-1 is clicked again. Third, it would be really great if Div5-1 and btnsContainer could also be hidden intially, and both slideToggle on mouseenter of Div-1 and slideUp on mouseleave of Div-1.  And as mentioned in the post, these are templated, so there are multiple Div-1 etc.

Comment: Here's a new question, if you prefer to post an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23522372/multiple-jquery-toggles-traversing-one-of-many-templated-elements

Comment: Really grateful for all of your guidance with this

Comment: Here's a solution.. Would definitely appreciate any better practice though, when you get to it: http://jsfiddle.net/qp477/8/