# Multiple jQuery Toggles, traversing One of Many Templated elements?

Tags: jquery, html, templates, toggle, traversal

I have a number of hidden elements that I would like have appear on certain jQuery events (.change, .click, .mouseenter, and .mouseleave). All of the elements repeat from templating, so the jQuery events need to traverse only the respective one.

Thanks to @ArunPJohny's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23466573/whats-the-correct-traversal-for-one-of-the-templated-elements-to-appear-with-jq), here's a fiddle of the current working version: http://jsfiddle.net/n6yq6/7/

And here's a fiddle outlining the ideal setup (has yet to work): http://jsfiddle.net/qp477/7/

Ideal HTML (with templating shown):

```
{{#each story)
<div class="Div1-1"><div class="Div1-2">
  <div class="Div2-1"><div class="Div2-2">2</div></div>
  <div class="Div3-1"><div class="Div3-2">3</div></div>
  <div class="Div4-1" style="display:none;">
    <div class="Div4-2-1"><div class="Div4-2-2">4</div></div>
    <div class="Div4-3-1"><div class="replyForm"><input type="text" /></div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="Div5-1" style="display:none;"><div class="Div5-2"><input type="text" /></div></div>
  <div class="btnsContainer" style="display:none;">
      <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
          <label class="btn btn1"><input type="checkbox" class="theBtn1"/>b1</label>
          <label class="btn btn2"><input type="checkbox" class="theBtn2"/>b2</label>
          <label class="btn btn3"><input type="checkbox" class="theBtn3"/>b3</label>
      </div>
  </div>
</div></div>

<div>
    <div class="DivA" style="display:none;">A</div>
    <div class="DivB" style="display:none;">B</div>
    <div class="DivC" style="display:none;">C</div>
</div>
{{/each}}
```

Outline of ideal jQuery (has yet to work):

```
// something to slideToggle Div5-1 & btnsContainer on mouseenter of Div1-1
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".Div1-1", function () {
    var $nxt = $(this).closest('.Div1-1').next();
    $nxt.children('.Div5-1').stop().slideToggle().toggleClass("active");;
    $nxt.children('.btnsContainer').stop().slideToggle().toggleClass("active");;
});
// something to slideUp Div5-1 & btnsContainer on mouseleave of Div1-1
$(document).on("mouseleave", ".Div1-1", function () {
    var $nxt = $(this).closest('.Div1-1').next();
    $nxt.children('.Div5-1').stop().slideUp().toggleClass("active");;
    $nxt.children('.btnsContainer').stop().slideUp().toggleClass("active");;
});

// something to slideToggle Div4-1 on click of Div3-1, and when visible slideUp Div4-1 on click of Div3-1
$(document).on("click", ".Div3-1", function () {
    var $nxt = $(this).closest('.Div1-1').next();
    $nxt.children('.Div4-1').stop().slideToggle().toggleClass("active");;
});

// toggle DivA on change of theBtn1, remove .active from theBtn2+theBtn3, and slideUp DivB+DivC (if open)
$(document).on("change", ".theBtn1", function () {
    var $nxt = $(this).closest('.Div1-1').next();
    $(".btn2").removeClass("active");
    $(".btn3").removeClass("active");
    $nxt.children().not('.DivA').stop().slideUp().removeClass("active");;
    $nxt.children('.DivA').stop().slideToggle().toggleClass("active");;
});
// toggle DivB on change of theBtn2, remove .active from theBtn1+theBtn3, and slideUp DivA+DivC (if open)
$(document).on("change", ".theBtn2", function () {
    var $nxt = $(this).closest('.Div1-1').next();
    $(".btn1").removeClass("active");
    $(".btn3").removeClass("active");
    $nxt.children().not('.DivB').stop().slideUp().removeClass("active");;
    $nxt.children('.DivB').stop().slideToggle().toggleClass("active");;
});
// toggle DivC on change of theBtn3, remove .active from theBtn1+theBtn2, and slideUp DivA+DivB (if open)
$(document).on("change", ".theBtn3", function () {
    var $nxt = $(this).closest('.Div1-1').next();
    $(".btn1").removeClass("active");
    $(".btn2").removeClass("active");
    $nxt.children().not('.DivC').stop().slideUp().removeClass("active");;
    $nxt.children('.DivC').stop().slideToggle().toggleClass("active");;
});
```

Comment: `$(this).closest('.Div1-1').find('whatever you want')` -- http://api.jquery.com/closest -- jQuery's docs have [a whole page of tree traversal methods](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/).

Comment: @Blazemonger very cool.. This solved it! One question though, it's a bit jumpy on the .click of Div3-1 when it closes.. Any suggestions for the jQuery jumpiness?

Comment: Not clear what you mean by that, sorry.

Comment: @Blazemonger hmm.. basically, on each .click for Div3 method it looks like the whole Div1-1 slides half an inch down and then back up.. This doesn't happen on jsfiddle though http://jsfiddle.net/qp477/8/ , so am wondering how to best explain